# fit_generator() unable to find get image because of a folder above it

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/OutTrainF/SPRING2388-D7-V40-H270.png'

The model cannot be trained as the image cannot be found because there is a folder above it which contains the image. Pls see screenshot below.  How can i solve this?

[![screenshot of output folder in Colab][1]][1]

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau,ModelCheckpoint,EarlyStopping

rlr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1,
                              patience=5, min_lr=0.00001, min_delta=0.001)
ckpt=ModelCheckpoint('models/checkpoint_female', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')  # for MALE / FEMALE RMB to change the model check point path 
es=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=20, min_delta=0.0001)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
                loss='mean_squared_error',
                metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

# model fit call for all data
history=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                           steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                           validation_data=valid_generator,
                           validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                           validation_freq=1,
                           epochs=50,
                           callbacks=[rlr,ckpt,es]) # ERROR IS GIVEN FROM THIS CALL BACK LINE OF CODE
# model fit call with validation

# save weights
model.save_weights('models/female.h5')
```

the DATA GENERATOR is from the below code:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    #featurewise_center=True,
    #featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    #width_shift_range=0.2,
    #height_shift_range=0.2,
    #horizontal_flip=True
)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=dfTrainF,
    directory='/content/OutTrainF/',
    x_col='name',
    y_col= ['0', '2'],   # diff for males/female      [str(genderindex[0]), str(genderindex[1])],
    batch_size=10,
    seed=42,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='raw',
    target_size=(224,448), 
    validate_filenames=False  # need this to bypass filename error, not found in original code.  
    #color_mode="grayscale"
)

valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=dfValF,
    directory='/content/OutValF/',
    x_col='name',
    y_col=['0', '2'],   # diff for males/female      [str(genderindex[0]), str(genderindex[1])],
    batch_size=10,
    seed=42,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='raw',
    target_size=(224,448),
    validate_filenames=False
    #color_mode="grayscale"
)

test_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=dfTestF,
    directory='/content/OutTestF/',
    x_col='name',
    y_col=['0', '2'],   # diff for males/female
    batch_size=10,
    seed=42,
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode=None,
    target_size=(224,448),
    validate_filenames=False
    #color_mode="grayscale"
)
```

Comment: Maybe adjust the paths given in your code?

Comment: the problem is that the folder name keeps on changing for different images, and i cannot just enter it in the path.